# Change CMD path from Python script

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I trying to create workspace in python for FASM (Flat assembler), C.
My problem is that, I don't want to keep all files, for e.g. FASM.exe, in main directory.
I want to create folder called 'Compilers/FASM' and store there all of FASM files.
I want to call programs using os.system().
The problem is when I trying to use FASM (FASM args at the end) by os.system('Compilers/FASM/FASM.exe projects/test/boot.asm projects/test/boot.bin'), I get information that FASM cannot find source file.
The FASM trying to compile files from Compilers/FASM/Projects/test/boot.asm, and this location does not exist.
If I would change path and add this folder (Compilers/FASM/) then I could use FASM.exe inside main directory.
When I had FASM inside main directory then execute command 'FASM.exe projects/test/boot.asm projects/test/boot.bin' was successful.

I was searching on googles and I couldn't find anything about change path for program. I tried to use os.system('path=Compilers/FASM'), but didn't work.
How can I change CMD path inside Python script?

FASM args:
FASM < source-file > [output file]

sorry for my English and text formatting

Comment: Could you try that again with some line breaks and an actual question?

Comment: Use the subprocess module instead of `os.system`: `retcode = subprocess.call(r'Compilers\FASM\FASM.exe projects\test\boot.asm projects\test\boot.bin', cwd=r'Compilers\FASM')`

Answer (score 0):

One way to address.this is using full path instead of relative ones.
For example you can do :

```
src = os.path.abspath('projects/test/boot.asm')
dst = os.path.abspath('projects/test/boot.bin')
os.system('Compilers/FASM/FASM.exe ' + src + ' ' + dst)
```

Comment: The only thing that I getting is the text about help and how to use FASM.
It is possible that FASM getting the current directory and adding source file to current directory, so I think the only way is to change path

Comment: I don't know FASM. Check the arguments provided by printing them before using os.system.